# Estimate a Rectangle from its Vertex

Tags: optimization, rectangles

Suppose i have estimated three points $\hat A$, $\hat B$ and $\hat C$ of a rectangle $ABCD$.

The fourth point can easily be: $\hat D=\hat A+(\hat C-\hat B)$.

But these points do not necessarily satisfy $\angle \hat A\hat B \hat C=90^\circ$ or the same for any other vertex. So $\hat A\hat B\hat C\hat D$ is not a rectangle.

Is there a proper way to *correct* those points in order $ABCD$ be a rectangle, under a minimal geometric error wrt the original points?.

We could assume the geometric error is: $$\sum_{X \in \{A,B,C,D\}} |X-\hat X|^2$$. Or any other metric.

Comment: Is this equivalent to finding the nearest right-angled triangle?

Comment: yes i think, provided that the error is minimum?

Comment: What error are we minimizing?

Comment: A least squares solution would be to find $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $(A-B)\cdot(B-C) = 0$ that minimizes $\|A-\hat{A}\|+\|B-\hat{B}\|+\|C-\hat{C}\|$

Comment: If A,B,C are points then $\angle \hat A \hat B$ is not an angle. I think this should be something containing ABC

Comment: What are the variables $X_i$?

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally set up this optimization problem with $x_i^0$ the original vertexs and $x_i$ the new vertex variable:

$$
\mathscr{P}) \min \sum_{i=1}^4 |x_i-x_i^0|^2\\
(x_1-x_2)^T(x_2-x_3)=0\\
x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4=\mathbb{0}\\
x_i^0 \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$

Which is solved in Matlab as:

```
x0=[0 0;1 0;1.2 1;0 1.2];
x=fmincon(@(x)fmin(x,x0),x0,...
    [],[],[],[],[],[],@(x)con(x));
```

with the square error:

```
function y=fmin(x,x0)
y=sum((x(1,:)-x0(1,:)).^2+(x(2,:)-x0(2,:)).^2+...
    (x(3,:)-x0(3,:)).^2+(x(4,:)-x0(4,:)).^2);
```

And the rect angle constraint and fourth point constraint:

```
function [y,yeq]=con(x)
y=[];
yeq(1)=(x(1,:)-x(2,:))*(x(2,:)-x(3,:))';
yeq(2:3)=(x(1,:)-x(2,:)+x(3,:)-x(4,:))';
```

The result is depicted through:

```
line([x0(:,1);x0(1,1)],[x0(:,2);x0(1,2)]);
hold on;
line([x(:,1);x(1,1)],[x(:,2);x(1,2)]);
hold off;
axis square;
```

Comment: If you set up an optimization problem than describe us this optimization problem using English language and mathematical notation. if you append code to this description then tell us in which language this code is written. Also it makes sense to add comment, e.g. if you draw a picture, then add a comment the tells this. Why should a reader that is not very familiar with matlab waste time to decipher this part of the code?

Comment: I will improve and "de-code" it to make it clearer...

Comment: Answer edited...

Comment: I turned the downvote in an upvote. Nevertheless I think it would make sense to mark the drawing of a picture by  a comment.  Also I dont understand he funny symbol $\mathscr{P})$

Comment: You will get used to that symbol.... it is classical :)... i will paste a picture later

Comment: What does it mean in this context?

Comment: Means the set of statements after the $\mathscr{P})$ formulate an optimization problem, first line a function to be min|max imized, next line statements to be satisfied. Ive failed to see any valid reference. Perhaps this is classical in excess

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about "minimal geometric error", but one possible solution could be to draw a circle whose diameter is the diagonal of the rectangle, $AC$. Then project $B$ onto the circumference of this circle to obtain $\hat B$ (i.e.: draw a line through $B$ and the center of the circle and take $\hat B$ to be where the line intersects the circle). This guarantees that $\angle A \hat B C = 90^\circ$. The missing fourth point $\hat D$ would be the reflection of $\hat B$ across the diagonal $AC$.